# La frase "la creazione di Adamo" è ambigua?

Tags: meaning

In portoghese, la frase "la creazione di Adamo" è ambigua se Adamo è la creatura o il creatore. E in italiano? È anche ambigua la frase?

[Tradotto con Google translate]

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Penso che anche in italiano abbia la stessa ambiguità.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sì, questa espressione è ambigua anche in italiano: può riferirsi a un'occasione in cui Adamo crea qualcosa (“genitivo soggettivo”) o all'atto con cui viene creato Adamo (“genitivo oggettivo”).

(In più, ma non penso che si riferisse a questo la domanda, la “creazione” può essere sia, appunto, l'atto del creare che il risultato di questo atto, e quindi ciò che viene creato.)